# Get all alike elements after a specific element, even if deeply nested

Tags: jquery, traversal

I want to get all the checkboxes **after** a specific element.
This checkboxes are in different divs and tables.
I tried:

```
$('.available').click(function() {
 $(this).nextAll("input:checkbox").each(function()
 {
   //code
 });
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your sample html

Comment: `nextAll` works if the elements are all siblings. You said you *tried*... have you been successful? If not, how do you expect anyone to help you without knowing *what* problem you face and what is the structure of your HTML document?

Comment: My answer below will work for all scenarios.

Comment: can you try `$(this).next().find("input:checkbox")` i havent tested just suggesting you check. probably it should work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to climb the DOM ([test case](http://jsfiddle.net/thejase/sTekh/)):

```
$(this)                                         
    .parents().andSelf()                         // get all parents of this as well
    .nextAll().find('input:checkbox').andSelf()  // get all siblings after and find any
    .filter('input:checkbox');                   // if real next sibling wasn't, kill it
```

Do keep in mind that **this is quite performance heavy**.  You are:

1. Climbing up the DOM (quite fast)
2. For each parent, getting all next siblings (semi-hefty)
3. Then, searching down each for checkboxes, repeating the same search multiple times on child nodes
4. Finally, filtering out any non-checkboxes left (have to go through found set once more)

This is *jQuery* magic, but there is definitely a better way outside of the ease of jQuery.  This might be O(n^n) complexity--the worst kind.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your specific element is a checkbox, but otherwise you'd have to start with a set that contains all checkboxes and your element:

```
var selector = ':checkbox, #target';
```

You could then find out the index of your element in that set, by using `index()`:

```
var targetIx = $('#target').index(selector);
```

And you would also be able to reduce your set to everything with after that index:

```
var elementsAfter = $(selector).slice(targetIx+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

`nextAll` will only get siblings, so...

first let's get all the checkboxes:

```
var checkboxes = $("input:checkbox");
```

next, prepare an array to hold just the ones we want:

```
var checkboxesslice = [];
```

now let's loop through them to looking for our starting point:

```
var startedyet = false;
for( var i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i+=1){
    if(startedyet){
        checkboxesslice.push(checkboxes[i]);
    }
    if(checkboxes[i] === $(this) ){
         startedyet = true;
    }     
}
```

This is totally untested, but you'll get the idea.